# Kubernetes volumeMount subpath always points to the same directory

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, persistent-volumes, azure-file-share

I'm using Kubernetes in Azure.

I created a persistent volume using an Azure NFS file share. I want to mount several subdirectories in the the NFS file system in several places in the running pod. However, when I use the subpath option in a volumeMount, the mount path always contains the root directory of my persistent volume.

Here is how I'm creating the persistent volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: file-share
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: {server info}
    path: /path-inside-file-share
  mountOptions:
    - vers=4
    - minorversion=1
    - noac
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: file-share
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
  volumeName: file-share
```

Then inside my Deployment I do this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: debug
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: debug
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: debug
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: debug
        image: docker.io/ubuntu
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args:
        - -c
        - >- 
            tail -f /dev/null

        volumeMounts:
        - name: file-share
          mountPath: /test/root

        - name: file-share
          mountPath: /test/foo1
          subpath: foo/
          
        - name: file-share
          mountPath: /test/foo2
          subpath: /foo/

        - name: file-share
          mountPath: /test/foo3
          subpath: /path-inside-file-share/foo/
          
        - name: file-share
          mountPath: /test/foo4
          subpath: foo

        - name: file-share
          mountPath: /test/foo5
          subpath: /foo

        - name: file-share
          mountPath: /test/foo6
          subpath: /path-inside-file-share/foo

      volumes:
      - name: file-share
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: file-share
```

With this configuration all of the foo directories inside the running pod have the same content as the root directory. The root directory contains a directory named "foo". I expect that the foo folder would be mounted at foo1, foo2, foo3, etc., But foo1, foo2, foo3 all contain the same contents as the root folder. I mounted foo with every combination of backslashes and relative paths I could think of.

```
root@debug-65668dcf88-qnxtm:/# cd test/
root@debug-65668dcf88-qnxtm:/test# ls
foo1  foo2  foo3  foo4  foo5  foo6  root
root@debug-65668dcf88-qnxtm:/test# ls root/
bar  foo  test.txt
root@debug-65668dcf88-qnxtm:/test# ls foo1  
bar  foo  test.txt
root@debug-65668dcf88-qnxtm:/test# ls foo2  
bar  foo  test.txt
root@debug-65668dcf88-qnxtm:/test# ls foo3  
bar  foo  test.txt
root@debug-65668dcf88-qnxtm:/test# ls foo4  
bar  foo  test.txt
root@debug-65668dcf88-qnxtm:/test# ls foo5  
bar  foo  test.txt
root@debug-65668dcf88-qnxtm:/test# ls foo6  
bar  foo  test.txt
root@debug-65668dcf88-qnxtm:/test#
```

Also, just for the record, I did the same test without a persistent volume, just mounting the NFS drive directly, and I got the same results.

Am I missing something? Is this just not possible with an Azure NFS file share?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the contents of the three directories to be different, you should create separate subdirectories in the NFS file share and mount each subdirectory to a different mount path in the pod.

For example, you could create the following subdirectories in the NFS file share:

```
/foo1
/foo2
/foo3
```

[image: NFS Sub directories]
Then, you could mount these subdirectories to the following mount paths in the pod:
[image: Sample YAML]

```
- name: file-share
  mountPath: /test/foo1
  subpath: foo1/

- name: file-share
  mountPath: /test/foo2
  subpath: foo2/

- name: file-share
  mountPath: /test/foo3
  subpath: foo3/
```

This will cause the Kubernetes scheduler to mount the correct subdirectory to the correct mount path, and the contents of the three directories will be different.
Sample YAML file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: debug
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: debug
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: debug
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: debug
        image: docker.io/ubuntu
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args:
        - -c
        - >-
            tail -f /dev/null

        volumeMounts:
        - name: file-share
          mountPath: /test/foo1
          subpath: foo1/

        - name: file-share
          mountPath: /test/foo2
          subpath: foo2/

        - name: file-share
          mountPath: /test/foo3
          subpath: foo3/

      volumes:
      - name: file-share
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: file-share
```

Comment: This is what I did in Azure Kubernetes service. However, it did not work. The folders I mounted with subpath always just mounted the root of the nfs share.